# Solving ODE by substitution. Where does $dy$ goes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When solving ODE by substitution, where does $dy$ goes from the following example?
$$\left(1+\frac{sin(y)}{cos(y)}\right)dy=x dx$$
Let $u=-cos(y)$. Hence $du = sin(y)$, which results in the following:
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{u}\right)du=xdx$$
But intuitively I want to write: $$\left(\left(1-(\frac{1}{u}du\right)\right)dy=xdx$$ 
So where did $dy$ go, could someone point out what logic eliminates $dy$ please?

Comment: Edits and improvements are welcome.

Comment: @Moo, Yes. Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitution should be $du \equiv \sin{(y)}dy$.

We define $u = -\cos{(y)}$, and so $$\frac{du}{dy} = \sin{(y)}.$$ By abuse of notation, we can intuitively "multiply this fraction" by $dy$— which would intuitively make $du \equiv \sin{(y)}dy$.

The equation $\left(1 + \frac{\sin{y}}{\cos{y}}\right) dy = x \,dx $ becomes

$$\left(1 + \frac{du}{-u}\right) = x \,dx$$

or just
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{u}\right)du = x \,dx.$$

Comment: O-o-o-h-h... That's what I was missing! $$du = sin(y)du$$ $$\frac{du}{dy}=sin(y)$$ Thank you!